# SQL - Max Case When not pulling max value?

Tags: sql

My problem is this:

A student can be enrolled in multiple English courses. I need to pull the student's highest English grade.

A particular student is enrolled in two English courses. One called English 8 and another called Reading/Writing 8.

In English 8, the student has an 82. In Reading/Writing 8, the student has a 100.

The following code is returning 82, and I want it to be returning 100.

`max(case when (B.CREDIT_TYPE = 'ENG' or D.SCHED_DEPARTMENT = 'ENG' or B.COURSE_NAME LIKE '%Integrated%' or B.CREDIT_TYPE = 'ENL' or D.SCHED_DEPARTMENT = 'ENL') then B.GRADE end) English`

I guess I don't know how the current code is working. The credit type and sched_department of both courses is ENG.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GRADE` is probably a string rather than a number.  If this is the case, you can convert it.  Assuming all values are numeric, you should fix your data to store it as a number:

```
alter table t alter grade decimal(5, 2) -- or whatever type is appropriate
```

In the meantime, you can convert it in the query:

```
then 0 + B.Grade
```

Do note that if `Grade` is not always a number, this could return a type conversion error in some databases.

Comment: I don't have permission to covert it from string to number unfortunately; I don't think anyone does. Is there any other way? I do think it is string, though, because when I use B.GRADE in an IN operator I have to have it in single parenthesis, like WHEN B.GRADE IN ('80','81'). It doesn't work without those so I suppose it is string.

Comment: I expect `0 + B.Grade` to raise an exception if B.Grade has a non-numeric data type.

Comment: @jarlh . . . Actually, if `B.Grade` is always numeric for these courses then the code should work regardless of database.  It will also "work" in MySQL, although the results may not be accurate.

Comment: Yay! It worked just adding 0+B.Grade! Thanks! I'm using ORACLE SQL for anyone reading.

Comment: Postgresql says "_ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying + integer_" even if the varchar value is an integer. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=928846f9bf45474769c27ca26de759e4

Comment: @jarlh . . . You are correct for Postgres, but the better comparison embeds it in a `case` expression: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8185fea5303dc0413b096d1818f2a93d.  Of the databases in db<>fiddle, only Postgres and Firebird return an error.  The rest accept the `+` as addition and do implicit conversion.

Comment: The SQL-2016 standard, section 6.29, "_3) The declared type of a <numeric primary> shall be numeric._"